# IE11 VM is no longer available for download - what are the other testing options?

Tags: internet-explorer, frontend, internet-explorer-11, microsoft-edge, ie11-developer-tools

It seems that the IE11 VM is no longer available from https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/ (why???)

What is everyone else using to test in IE11 locally? Browserstack is not an option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, problem solved - the VM actually contains both IE11 and Edge.

Answer (score 1):

Everything looks fine on my side, I could download the VM from [that link](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/vms/) using IE 11. The screenshot as below:

[image]

Please click the IE browser Tools and open the View Downloads (Ctrl+J) window to check whether it contains the download progress.

Besides, please check your Network, make sure it is connected, and you could also use F12 developer tools to check whether there is some error in the web page(when you click the platform to download the VM).

Comment: The link is for a VM with Edge - I need a VM containing IE11. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This Virtual Machine using Windows 10 with Legacy Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer 11, it already installed IE 11.